# Multivariable Calculus triple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need some help setting up the integral for this review question.

$\qquad$Find the volume enclosed by$\;\;x^2+z^2=4,\;\;y=z,\;\;y+z=4$.

More specifically, I needed help setting the bounds. My initial thought was to use a triple integral and set $y$ between $z$ and $4-z$ and then to use polar coordinates to set up the double integral in the $xz$-plane, but I couldn't quite get it. I appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was fine.

For conceptual simplicity, switch the variables $y$ and $z$.

The bounding equations are then
$$x^2+y^2=4,\;\; z=y,\;\;z+y=4$$
From $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, we get $y \le 2$, hence $y \le 4-y$, so $z$ varies from $y$ to $4-y$.

Switching to cylindrical coordinates, the region $E$ can be expressed as the set of points $(r,\theta,z)$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
0 \;\le\; &r \;\le\; 2\\[4pt]
0 \;\le\; &\theta \;\le\; 2\pi\\[4pt]
r\sin\theta \;\le\; &z \;\le\; 4-r\sin\theta\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus, the volume of the region $E$ is given by
\begin{align*}
V &=\iiint_{E}1\,dV\\[4pt] 
&= \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^2\int_{z=r\sin\theta}^{4-r\sin\theta}r\,dzdrd\theta\\[4pt]
&= \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^2 r(4-2r\sin\theta)\,drd\theta\\[4pt]
&= \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \bigl(\!{-\small{\frac{16}{3}}}\bigr)\!\sin\theta+8\,d\theta\\[4pt] 
&=16\pi\\[4pt]
\end{align*}